# Grails Domain: How to access parent domain data?

Tags: validation, grails, groovy, grails-orm, domain-object

I have a parent child domain structure, and I want access parent domain data in child domain for validator. For example in the code example below, child1 has a variable 'name' and for validator purpose I need child2 data.

How can I achieve this situation?

I have domain structure like this:

```
class Parent{
    Child child1
    Child child2

    static mapping = {
        child1 lazy:false
        child2 lazy:false
    }
}

class Child{
    String name
    // some other variables

    static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]

    static constraints = {
        name(nullable:true,validator:{val, obj ->
            if(obj.parent){
                return true
            }
            return false
        })
    }
}
```

I tried
`this.parent.child2`
but parent is found null.

EDIT:
Changed:
`static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]`

Also added in validator:
`if(obj.parent){
    return true
}
return false`

Still it is returning false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
static belongsTo = [Parent]
```

with

```
static belongsTo = [parent: Parent]
```

so the child know its parent

Answer (score 0):

To build on @bassmartin's answer, Check the [documentation](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) for custom validators.  Your validator should declare (at least) two arguments, the second of which is the object instance:

```
validator: { val, obj ->
  //obj.parent is what you're looking for
}
```

Comment: obj.parent is still null. Is there anything missing?